# Condition number of a matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am finding it difficult to compute the condition number of a matrix using Mathematica. There is no built-in function, it seems, for this task. MatLab and Numpy have it. All stack searches point to some old linear algebra package.

```
m={{-639445.,-336053.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.683542,0.,0.151787},{-336053.,-7.4485*10^6,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.0000174204,0.,0.808413},{0.,0.,-6.19065*10^15,2.20989*10^10,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-1427.52},{0.,0.,2.20989*10^10,-6.50127*10^16,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,2496.12},{0.,0.,0.,0.,-4.19983*10^9,0.,0.,0.,1.33685*10^-12,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-6.1685*10^11,0.,-1.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-5.55165*10^12,1.,0.,0.},{0.683542,-0.0000174204,0.,0.,0.,-1.,1.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,1.33685*10^-12,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.151787,0.808413,-1427.52,2496.12,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.}}
```

How can I compute the condition number for matrix `m`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to estimate the matrix condition number in the 2-Norm?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52367/how-to-estimate-the-matrix-condition-number-in-the-2-norm)

Comment: The condition number can be defined as the ratio of the magnitude largest singular value to the smallest. "SingularValueList" gives you a list of singular values.  Therefore, condition number= SingularValueList[[1]]/SingularValueList[[-1]]

Comment: @DanielHuber The ratio value is different with [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267941/21532)

Comment: The definition of the condition number depends on the choice of norm. Look it up on the internet.

Comment: The Wolfram MathWorld entry for [Condition Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConditionNumber.html) may be of interest, as may [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52367/106#comment158588_52367) by Daniel Lichtblau and [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/201862/106#comment521636_201862) by Carl Woll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> MatLab and Numpy has it

Mathematica has it also, but hiding in the following function

```
 LUDecomposition[m][[3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

Comment: But how to compute p-2 norm

Comment: @VijayKumarS for p-2, you can check the other quesition in the link given in the comments to your question. I agree that Mathematica should really have a dedicated function condition number using different norms and not just infinity.

Comment: I tried with `LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[m, Norm -> 2]`, its not working. I think its time for mathematica to introduce a function to calculate the condition number insted on relaying  on  by products of other functions.

Comment: @VijayKumarS The internals of the `LinearAlgebra` context have changed a few times. It is not an official (documented) part of Mathematica. The function is now found as ``LinearAlgebra`Private`MatrixConditionNumber[m, Norm -> p]`` (see yode's and my answers); but only `p = 1` and `p = Infinity` are currently supported. For the 2-norm, use `SingularValueList`.

Answer (score 8):

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`MatrixConditionNumber[m]
```

> 1.52779*10^50

Comment: Is that command documented?

Comment: @user64494 Apparently not

Answer (score 8):

It's also hidden in

```
LinearSolve[m]@"ConditionNumber"
(*  1.52779*10^50  *)
```

This gives the infinity norm (from the LU decomposition).

The 1-norm may be obtained with

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`MatrixConditionNumber[m, Norm -> 1]
```

It's the same in this case because `m` is symmetric.

And the 2-norm may be obtained from `SingularValueList`, as may be found in the Q&A, [How to estimate the matrix condition number in the 2-Norm?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52367/how-to-estimate-the-matrix-condition-number-in-the-2-norm)
(For a large matrix, one can compute the largest and smallest singular values separately.)